# Set default value in @Html.TextboxFor MVC Core 2

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a text box that upon initial page load (and assuming an empty model) the html TextBoxFor helper populates a text box with 0.  Since 0 is a value, I want to change this behavior to "" (null, nothing, etc.).  Given the amount of literature out there on this, I thought this should be straightforward; however, I can't get it to work.  Here's what I've got (I've parsed it down to keep it simple, pardon any mistakes)

Model:

```
public class Something_ViewModel
{ [DisplayName("Feet:")]
    public int Feet{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult RetainedOwnership()
    {
        Models.Analytics.Something_ViewModel RO_VM = new Models.Analytics.Something_ViewModel();
       Return View(RO_VM);
    }
```

And the tag Helpers I've tried:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Feet, new { id = "txtFeet", @Value = Model.Feet.ToString() ?? "" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Feet, new { id = "txtFeet", Value = Model.Feet.ToString() ?? "" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Feet, new { id = "txtFeet", Value = "" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Feet, new {Value = "" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Feet, new {@Value = "" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Feet, new {id = "txtFeet"})
```

Comment: Under no circumstances should you ever set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change `Feet` datatype to `int?`. Default value for that would be null.

Comment: That worked.  For everyone else this is what I discovered- int, decimal, float, etc. value types are by default required and non-nullable.  If you want it to be nullable, you have to do this:System.Nullable<int> or the shorthand for this is int? .